# Is there a better tutorial for creating a custom dimension for Client ID in Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager than this?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

This is my first custom dimension and when I try to use it in my Analytics custom report it says: **There is no data for this view.**

I created a custom dimension in GA property which gave me 1 as index

I created 2 variables in Google Tag Manager:

{{Analytics Settings}} variable with UA tracking number and I set custom dimension index to 1 and value to: Client ID

{{Set Client ID in Dimension 1}} variable with custom JavaScript

```
function() {
    var customDimensionIndex = 1;
  return function(model) {
    model.set('dimension' + customDimensionIndex, model.get('clientId'));
  }
}
```

Then I created a Universal Analytics Tag with:

Track type: PageView

Google analytics settings: {{Analytics Settings}}

Override: ticked

Field Name: customTask

Value: {{Set Client ID in Dimension 1}}

Triggering: All Pages

Then I also set up a trigger for the container: Page View

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: What you mean with 'and I set custom dimension index to 1 and value to: Client ID'? You don't need it, just customTask

Comment: Okay I removed the Google Analytics variable completely from the tag. This still gives me the same result though.

Comment: You can follow this guideline: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/use-customtask-access-tracker-values-google-tag-manager/

Comment: It's also not working, I even created the field cookieDomain as the guideline's image shows with value set to auto. I only have these settings now:  It's a Universal Analytics Tag with:

Track type: PageView

Override: ticked

Field Name: customTask

Value: {{Set Client ID in Dimension 1}}

Triggering: All Pages

Comment: Try to configure customTask in Analytics settings (removing it from override). What you see in preview?

Answer (score 0):

Use customTask to get the ClientID from tracker object.
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions